# Gesoservices provider is not supported on an Android using Mapbox with QT

Tags: android, qt, mapbox

I'm trying to run a simple example of Mapbox using the QT SDK.
On my mac it's ok but when the example run on my Android phone, I saw a blank map and if I call the function errorString on the Map object, I got this error message:

> The geoservices provider is not supported.

Can anyone help me?
My Mapbox key is valid, I did the test as they suggest on the MapBox web site.

I am using QT 5.12 and my LG5 phone is on Android 8.0.

What I don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/11139) this is appears to be an issue with the Qt Location plugin and not with Mapbox GL. A quick sweep of [existing tickets](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTWEBSITE-855?jql=) to see if this has already been reported comes up empty, so I'd recommend flagging it for the Qt engineering team here: https://bugreports.qt.io/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is some kind of a dependency resolution bug and QT APK bundler does not add several shared libraries like

```
libplugins_geoservices_qtgeoservices_mapboxgl_armeabi-v7a.so
libQt5OpenGL_armeabi-v7a.so
libQt5Sql_armeabi-v7a.so
```

This is what fixes it (found it in mapviewer QT example). Add to your .pro file:

```
# Workaround for QTBUG-38735
QT_FOR_CONFIG += location-private
qtConfig(geoservices_mapboxgl): QT += sql opengl
qtConfig(geoservices_osm): QT += concurrent
```

In case you are using CMake builds adding Qt5::Sql and Qt5::OpenGL along with Qt5::Location also fixes the issue:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Positioning Location Sql OpenGL)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        Qt5::Location
        Qt5::Positioning
        Qt5::Sql
        Qt5::OpenGL
        )
```

Comment: In Qt 5.15 helped adding Qt += sql and Qt += location with qmake.