# Map doesn't appear in Android emulator

Tags: android, qt, qml, mapbox

I have a simple QT project with a single QML view, with inside a MapBox; for some reason, if I run the project as a desktop app, all works and the map appears. If I run the project inside an Android emulator, the map doesn't appear and the screen is white. Why? I put below all info about the (small) project, including also the output I see by compiling.

I already tried several solutions I found on the web, but without success because the problem is not related to the components QTLocation / QTComponent it selfs (they are correctly installed, as you can see below, otherwise the app wouldn't work in a desktop view).

CMakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
    
    project(mapTest VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
    
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
    
    set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
    set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
    
    
    # QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
    # Check https://doc.qt.io/qt/deployment-android.html for more information.
    # They need to be set before the find_package(...) calls below.
    
    
    #if(ANDROID)
    #    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    #    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
    #        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
    #            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
    #            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
    #    endif()
    #endif()
    
    
    
    
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
    find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

//Added in the editing

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED Positioning Location Sql OpenGL)
    
    
    
    
    set(PROJECT_SOURCES
            main.cpp
            qml.qrc
    )
    
    
    
    
    if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
        qt_add_executable(mapTest
            MANUAL_FINALIZATION
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        if(ANDROID)
            add_library(mapTest SHARED
                ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
            )
        else()
            add_executable(mapTest
              ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
            )
        endif()
    endif()
    
    
    
    
    target_compile_definitions(mapTest
      PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
    target_link_libraries(mapTest
      PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick

//Added in the editing


        Qt5::Location
        Qt5::Positioning
        Qt5::Sql
        Qt5::OpenGL
    
    )
    
    
    set_target_properties(mapTest PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    )
    
    
    if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
        qt_import_qml_plugins(mapTest)
        qt_finalize_executable(mapTest)
    endif()
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif


    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12

Window {

    title: "Title"
    id: containerWindow
    visible: true
    visibility: Qt.WindowFullScreen

    Plugin {
        id: mapboxglPlugin
        name: "mapboxgl"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapboxglPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(60.170448, 24.942046) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 10
        id: mapMain
        copyrightsVisible: false
    }
}
```

Application output:

```
    I example.MapTes: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I example.MapTes: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W example.MapTes: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I ndk_translation: Initialized NDK translation (armv7l), version 0.2.2
D ApplicationLoaders: Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
D Qt JAVA : Class org.qtproject.qt5.android.positioning.QtPositioning does not implement setActivity method
I QtCore  : Start
I Qt      : qt started
I QtPositioning: Positioning start
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ViewDrawableStates:[I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_background:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_padding:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_paddingLeft:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_paddingTop:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_paddingRight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_paddingBottom:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollX:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollY:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_id:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_tag:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_fitsSystemWindows:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_focusable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_focusableInTouchMode:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_clickable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_longClickable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_saveEnabled:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_duplicateParentState:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_visibility:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_drawingCacheQuality:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_contentDescription:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_soundEffectsEnabled:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_hapticFeedbackEnabled:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbars:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_fadingEdge:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarStyle:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarFadeDuration:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarSize:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarThumbHorizontal:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarThumbVertical:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarTrackHorizontal:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_scrollbarTrackVertical:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_isScrollContainer:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_keepScreenOn:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_filterTouchesWhenObscured:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_nextFocusLeft:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_nextFocusRight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_nextFocusUp:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_nextFocusDown:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_minWidth:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_minHeight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_onClick:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_overScrollMode:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_paddingStart:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->View_paddingEnd:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textColorHighlight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textColor:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textColorHint:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textColorLink:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textSize:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_typeface:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textStyle:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance_textAllCaps:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_editable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_inputMethod:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_numeric:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_digits:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_phoneNumber:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_autoText:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_capitalize:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_bufferType:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_selectAllOnFocus:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_autoLink:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_linksClickable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawableLeft:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawableTop:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawableRight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawableBottom:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawableStart:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawableEnd:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_drawablePadding:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textCursorDrawable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_maxLines:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_maxHeight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_lines:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_height:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_minLines:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_minHeight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_maxEms:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_maxWidth:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_ems:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_width:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_minEms:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_minWidth:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_gravity:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_hint:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_text:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_scrollHorizontally:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_singleLine:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_ellipsize:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_marqueeRepeatLimit:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_includeFontPadding:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_cursorVisible:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_maxLength:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textScaleX:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_freezesText:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_shadowColor:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_shadowDx:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_shadowDy:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_shadowRadius:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_enabled:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textColorHighlight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textColor:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textColorHint:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textColorLink:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textSize:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_typeface:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textStyle:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_password:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_lineSpacingExtra:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_lineSpacingMultiplier:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_inputType:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_imeOptions:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_imeActionLabel:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_imeActionId:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_privateImeOptions:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textSelectHandleLeft:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textSelectHandleRight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textSelectHandle:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textIsSelectable:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextView_textAllCaps:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_src:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_baselineAlignBottom:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_adjustViewBounds:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_maxWidth:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_maxHeight:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_scaleType:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_tint:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->ImageView_cropToPadding:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->TextAppearance:[I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->Window:[I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/R$styleable;->Window_windowBackground:I (greylist-max-q, reflection, allowed)
W example.MapTes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable$GradientState;->mShape:I (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
W System.err: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mShape
W System.err:   at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1604)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getGradientDrawable(ExtractStyle.java:672)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getDrawable(ExtractStyle.java:1039)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getStateListDrawable(ExtractStyle.java:652)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.getDrawable(ExtractStyle.java:1035)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.extractWindow(ExtractStyle.java:1942)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.ExtractStyle.<init>(ExtractStyle.java:2002)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtActivityDelegate.loadApplication(QtActivityDelegate.java:631)
W System.err:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.loadApplication(QtLoader.java:267)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp(QtLoader.java:505)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate(QtActivityLoader.java:166)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreateHook(QtActivity.java:267)
W System.err:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:274)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
W System.err:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
W System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
W System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
W System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
W System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
W System.err:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
```

Comment: see `libmapTest_armeabi-v7a.so: 1 ,  "The geoservices provider is not supported."`

Comment: check this link if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54971977/gesoservices-provider-is-not-supported-on-an-android-using-mapbox-with-qt

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping; by following the example you indicated me, the output is changed. I update my original question in one minute.

Comment: Ok Usama, after adding the link to QTLocation and QTPositioning also in my CMakeLists.txt file, now I see an empty mapbox (The background is changed and now I see at the bottom the map credit) but the map is not here. Also the output is completely changed, I have updated it. Thanks again, I feel that we are in the near of the solution.